# Solving the wave PDE using the Fourier method

Tags: plotting, differential-equations

I am trying to solve the wave PDE using the Fourier method and I need to animate the plots of  the partial sum of order 45 -- U45(x,t) with initial conditions U45(x,t0), {t0, 0, 12, .2}.

I am confused: should I define the function f[x, t, k_] or should I do it as f[x, k_] and later access the 't'.

```
a[k_] := 
  Piecewise[{
    {2/(k*π) Integrate[Cos[(k*π*x)/6] (2 - x) Sin[π*x]^2, {x, 1, 3}], k != 0},
    {1/6 Integrate[(2 - x) Sin[π*x]^2, {x, 1, 3}], k == 0}}]

f[x, t, k_] := 
  a[0]*t + Sum[a[i] Cos[(i*π*x)/6] Sin[(i*π*t)/6], {i, k}]

sol = f[x, t, 45];
```

Anyway, the above is the piece of code I've written so far. Tried a dozen different Plot3D combinations, but the error I receive tells me I can not replace t. I am open to everything tutorials, papers, tips, plain solutions, everything.

Comment: Please consider using an ASCII equivalent for your name if such a thing exists to make it easier for others to interact with you here.  According to Google Translate that is Nikola Dimitrov.  Is that acceptable to you?

Comment: Yes, I am sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: No problem, and thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your definition of `f` you should have `f[x_,t_,k_]`, `x_` means *"Match anything and let it be referenced by `x`"* you might want to read about patterns in general in the documentation.

```
Clear[a, f];
a[k_] := Piecewise[{
   {0, k == 12},
   {(1728 (k (-144 + k^2) \[Pi] Cos[(k \[Pi])/6]
    - 18 (-48 + k^2) Sin[(k \[Pi])/6]) Sin[(k \[Pi])/3])
         /(k^3 (-144 + k^2)^2 \[Pi]^3), k != 0},
   {0, k == 0}}]

f[x_, t_, k_] := a[0]*t + Sum[a[i] Cos[(i*\[Pi]*x)/6] Sin[(i*\[Pi]*t)/6], {i, k}]

Plot3D[f[x, t, 45], {x, -1, 1}, {t, 0, 2}]
```

[image: plot]

I replaced the `Integrate` in your definition of `a` to not have to calculate it over and over again, thereby speeding up the plot.

Comment: I *heart* `NDSolve`

Comment: Thank you for your explanation and reference ! :)

Comment: +1 for adding the speed hint. To be more pedagogical, it's worth pointing out that the definition of `a[k_]` was OK in principle, *except* for the little difference between `:=` and `=`. In this case, all that was needed is to use the latter (`Set`) to get the same speedup that you achieved by copying and pasting into the definition of `a[k_]`.

Comment: @Jens Yea, problem was that for `k=12` the integral should be zero but the resulting expression was undefined (limit was still zero though) so had to do it manually anyway

Comment: Right, that was probably an oversight in the original `Piecewise`...